# Knockout observable array randomly doesn't bind

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, sammy.js

I'm having a problem with durandal/knockout/sammy - not sure which one is the culprit. Occasionally my var roots = ko.observableArray([]); doesn't get bound to the UI. Most of the time it works perfectly. Hopefully someone on SO sees something I don't.

VM Activate:

```
var activate = function () {
        groupsData.GetRoots().then(function (data) {
            roots($.map(data, function (it) { return new groupNode.GroupNode(it); }));
//If I do a console.log(roots()); right here, the correct data shows up
        });
    };
```

DataContext:

```
var getRoots = function () {
    return Q.when($.getJSON(Url));
};
```

My view: 
If I hit refresh over and over, the span with the 'length' in it will show the correct length MOST OF THE TIME. Occasionally it will be 0 and the UI inside of the foreach will not show.

```
    <span data-bind="text: roots().length"></span>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: roots">
        //BLA
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `return` the promise in the `activate` function, otherwise it won't know when the promise has completed.

```
var activate = function () {
    return groupsData.GetRoots().then(function (data) {
        roots($.map(data, function (it) { return new groupNode.GroupNode(it); }));
    });
};
```

If you do this, databinding wont occur until the promise has finished, which will remove the race condition you are seeing.